# Spark.sql not working on EMR (Serverless)

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr, delta-lake

The following script does not create the table in the S3 location indicated by the query.
I tested it locally and the Delta Json file was created and contained the information about the table.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = (SparkSession
    .builder
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .appName('omop_ddl')
    .getOrCreate()
    )


spark.sql(f"""
CREATE
OR REPLACE TABLE CONCEPT (
  CONCEPT_ID LONG,
  CONCEPT_NAME STRING,
  DOMAIN_ID STRING,
  VOCABULARY_ID STRING,
  CONCEPT_CLASS_ID STRING,
  STANDARD_CONCEPT STRING,
  CONCEPT_CODE STRING,
  VALID_START_DATE DATE,
  VALID_END_DATE DATE,
  INVALID_REASON STRING
) USING DELTA
LOCATION 's3a://ls-dl-mvp-s3deltalake/health_lakehouse/silver/concept';
""")
```

The configuration parameters are the following ones:

```
--conf spark.jars=s3a://ls-dl-mvp-s3development/spark_jars/delta-core_2.12-2.1.0.jar,s3a://ls-dl-mvp-s3development/spark_jars/delta-storage-2.1.0.jar 
--conf spark.executor.cores=1 
--conf spark.executor.memory=4g 
--conf spark.driver.cores=1 
--conf spark.driver.memory=4g 
--conf spark.executor.instances=1
```

I tried to modify the location in the query by inserting a non-existent bucket and the script did not go into error. Am I forgetting something? I know I could try with the Dataframe API but I'd like to stick with Sql Syntax.
Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Would the table be created in the correct location if you comment out `enableHiveSupport()`

Comment: Tried to comment out enableHiveSupport method but still nothing :(

Comment: Got it - to confirm, are you running into any issues if you tired to save this as Parquet instead of doing this as Delta?